# UWP Open 2x Server Listening (BindServiceNameAsync("some port#)) in 1 Apps

Tags: c#, vb.net, uwp, windows-iot-core-10

For UWP, I try to open 2 ports to listen incoming connection:

```
BindServiceNameAsync("6000")
BindServiceNameAsync("6001")
```

Unfortunately I cannot make it work, whichever listening port get first connection with TCP client the other port cannot be connected.

My code is like this:

```
Public Async Sub IDPserverStart()
    Dim socketListener = New Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener
    AddHandler socketListener.ConnectionReceived, AddressOf TCPconnectedProcess
    Try
        Await socketListener.BindServiceNameAsync("6001")

    Catch ex As Exception
        socketListener.Dispose()
        Debug.WriteLine("IDPserverStart() ERR: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Async Sub OPSserverStart()
    Dim socketListener = New Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener
    AddHandler socketListener.ConnectionReceived, AddressOf OPSconnectedProcess
    Try
        Await socketListener.BindServiceNameAsync("6000")
    Catch ex As Exception
        socketListener.Dispose()
        Debug.WriteLine("OPSserverStart() ERR: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limitation for listening port per apps on Windows IoT Core. The reason is the firewall rules for connection security policy. Please add the firewall rule to Windows IoT Core like below cmdlet by [using PowerShell for windows IoT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/connect-your-device/powershell) or running command in Device Portal(Processes->Run command):

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 6001" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=6001
```

BTW.You can use the following cmdlet to check the rules in your device.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule status=enabled name=all
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have checked the **Private Networks (Client & Server)** Capability in the server app's Package.appxmanifest, then test the connection among different devices.

Comment: Checked Private Network (Client & Server) in manifest but no luck. I developing Windows IoT Core. Unfortunately not working. Perhaps there is limitation 1 server listening port per apps. I think it might be the limitation but could not find any document pointed to my statement